# Access Single Child Controller From Repeat?

Tags: angularjs

The best way to explain would be this example:

```
<table ng-controller="groupOfPeopleController">
    <tr ng-repeat "person in peoples">
       <td>{{person.name}}</td>
       <td><button ng-click="load_data(person.id)">Load Data</button>
       <td><div class="personData" ng-controller="personDataController"></div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

What I'm looking to do is populate div.personData with it's own data.  So I have a function in groupOfPeopleController called load_data(id):

```
// groupOfPeopleController
$scope.load_data = function(id){
    $rootScope.$broadcast('load_data'id);
}
```

that I would like to pass specifically to the child element controller personData.

```
// personDataController
$scope.$on('load_data',function(e,id){
   // hopefully affect only the div inside the current loop...
});
```

The problem is, it is attached to every loop of personData.  So a click on one person, affects every row, seeing as they are all attached to the same controller.

How would I go about making separate instances of personData? Is broadcast the wrong way to go about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not broadcast from $rootScope, which will dispatches an event name downwards to all child scopes (and their children recursively).

What you could do, is just broadcast from from the current scope, rather than all scopes. See this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/2MYLPokzu7j5dkZa7xGd?p=preview).

The main trick is that you need the child scope ng-repeat creates, so you pass the keyword "this" to your function which gets the current scope, then from there you broadcast the event.

element:

```
<button ng-click="load_data(this, person.id)">Load Data</button>
```

groupOfPeopleController:

```
$scope.load_data = function(childScope, id){
  childScope.$broadcast('load_data', id);
}
```

However, I recommend against this method.  Why have any broadcasts/$on's at all?  You could simply move the personDataController to the entire contents of the tr, and have the loadData function called directly from the ng-click like in [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/IBwAg7tgAw5vRDP0H7bJ?p=preview). It's save you some headaches and bugs.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use broadcast for that. Yes, events are good but not in this case. 
And your items in the loop is being updated because every item in the loop receives reference to the same controller not an instance of it.

Correct way of doing that would be using directives.

Change your template to:

```
<tr ng-repeat="person in peoples" data-person="person"></tr>
```

and use directive something like this:

```
app.directive('person', function(){
    var templateStr = '<td>{{person.name}}</td>' +
        '<td><button ng-click="load_data(person.id)">Load Data</button>' +
        '<td><div class="personData">{{person.anyDataYouWantToDisplay}}</div></td>';
    var linkFn = function(scope){
       scope.load_data = function(id){
           // load person data and do something about it
       };
       // do other magic here as it is the controller for your individual person
    };
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            person: '='
        }
        link: linkFn,
        template: templateStr
    };
});
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: This helps tremendously.  Thank you for your input.  I chose the other answer because it was a little closer to what I'd done already. But, a great answer none-the-less.